# Vite PWA plugin - add to home screen event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vite

I'm trying to add an installable button to my PWA application. Everywhere I find information about beforeinstallprompt event but i cant listen it. I tried this code:

```js
    window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", e => {
      console.log("???")
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
      this.deferredPrompt = e;
    });
```

into my component - in created hook and mounted, into my App.vue, into my service worker but every time it has no effect my app does not go inside listener, i tried console.log something and it don't runs.

I used Vite PWA Plugin is there any other way to add this button?

regards.

UPDATE

here is my code:

```js
  data: () => ({
    deferredPrompt: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.captureEvent();
  },
  methods: {
    captureEvent() {
      window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
        e.preventDefault();
        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        this.deferredPrompt = e;
      });
    },

    clickCallback() {
      // Show the prompt
      this.deferredPrompt.prompt();
      // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
      this.deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
        if (choiceResult.outcome === "accepted") {
          // Add analyticcs event
          this.$gtag.event("add_to_home_screen");
        }
        this.deferredPrompt = null;
      });
    },
  },
```

and it runs only after lighthouse audit... dont work in desktop chrome, firefox, dont work on android, iphone. I'm using https btw.

do you guys have an idea why it might be like this?